# Jquery unobtrusive not working in onkeyup false

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to disable Jquery unobtrusive validation for my current form on keyup I am using the below code but its not working. I want to allow validation only on submit form.

```
  $.validator.setDefaults(
        {
            onkeyup: false,
            blur: false,
            focusInvalid: false
        });
```

Comment: `$.validator.setDefaults({ onkeyup: false });` should work, but if you only want it on form submit, then you may need to disable validation in the `.blur()` event as well

Comment: Do I need to put it after  $('.validate').validate(); or before

Comment: It needs to inside `<script>` tags after the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files. And you should not need or have `$('.validate').validate();` (not clear why you have that)

Comment: I am using a single minified file for all js using bower

Comment: That wont make any difference :)

Comment: I have tried blur and onkeyup doesnot works for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123749/discussion-between-maxspan-and-stephen-muecke).